# {sk-learn} Can Select-K-Best pruning decrease the performance?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, feature-selection, supervised-learning

My base model is a logistic regression classifier with 65 features.

I now extrapolate all possible polynomial features from these 65 features and then do a *SelectKBest* pruning of top 100 features (using *chi2* criteria).
When I compare this to my base model, I see considerable reduction in precision and recall.

My question  is why would *selectKBest* reduce the performance in any scenario? If the extrapolated polynomial features are not useful then it should have selected the original 65 features thereby giving me either same or better performance as the base model.

I cannot comprehend how can selectKBest feature pruning hurt my performance?

Answer (score 0):

chi2 critera is not magic; polynomial features may be especially hard for chi2 to get right, as chi2 feature selection works by eliminating features with high *linear* dependency between them.

UPDATE:

Let's say we have features x and y; x=2y. Polynomial expansion up to 2 degree will give us x, y, xy, x^2 and y^2. If we substitute x=2y, we get 2y, y, 2y^2, 4y^2 and y^2.

After chi2 selection we should be left with something like y and y^2, as these are the only linear independent features. Depending on data and classifier, new polynomial feature y^2 could make result worse or better, there are no performance guarantees whatever.

As you can see, chi2 doesn't back up to selecting original y feature, it keeps y^2 as well, even in this simplistic example.

In the real world there will be tradeoffs during feature selection. For example, if there is feature z which is correlated with y, but not perfectly (i.e. it provides additional information, but not much), then chi2 test will likely eliminate z, but not y^2, as y^2 doesn't have a linear dependency on y, while z has. Keeping z is better in this case, as z provides additional information, unlike y^2. This is an example of how chi2 test may eliminate an useful feature and keep a redundant one.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it revert back to the original features rather than choosing ones that hurt the performance? Pardon me if I am missing something here.

Comment: chi2 does not gurantee anything about performance; it doesn't even know what the performance is (i.e. labels are not used). So it is totally possible for it to hurt performance. But that's a good question. I've expanded my asnwer.